# extension method phone format with country code as parameter

Tags: c#

I'm writing an extension method called ToPhoneFormat that formats a string of digits to phone numbers.

Is it possible to add a parameter to the method that would enable me to call it like this: MyPhoneString.ToPhoneFormat(international code)

That way, I could write MyPhoneString.ToPhoneFormat(1); to format a US phone number and MyPhoneString.ToPhoneFormat(33) to format a French phone number.

I already wrote the method that does the formatting but I'm wondering how to build the constructor so that it works with a parameter when I'm calling it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nice and easy :)

I'm assuming your method signature for ToPhoneFormat looks something like:

```
public static string ToPhoneFormat(this string sourceString) 
{
    /* Your code here */ 
}
```

if so, the all you need to do is add a parameter after the `this` parameter, so it becomes:

```
public static string ToPhoneFormat(this string sourceString, int countryCode)
{
    /* Your code here */
}
```

Comment: ThisFormat = sourceStringe.Format("{0:###-###-####}"); doesn't work. What's wrong with this line?

Comment: @frenchie: Create a new question. It's easier to provide an example string and desired result and what's not working, than a single line comment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, extension methods can take parameters:

```
public static string ToPhoneFormat(this string str, int formatCode)
{
    return ...
}

// ...

string s = "1234567890".ToPhoneFormat(33);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure. You can just add the parameter in the extension method's signature:

```
public static string ToPhoneFormat(this string phoneNumber, int countryCode)
{
   // do your formatting here
}
```